# Adding Values In Dictionary With Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I have this Dictionary:

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
```

and I want to add the values for example to have the result as 30 , how can I do that? In other words, how can I only add the numbers, not the words?

Comment: This is easy. What part don't you know how to do?

Comment: I do not know if it's Christmas but I'm not managing to get this

Comment: But please show that you have tried _something_. I could just write your code for you, but that is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. I want to _help_ you, not do your work _for_ you.

Comment: Do you know how to extract the values from a dictionary? Do you know how to sum an array?

Comment: for value i used for name in dict.values {
    println(name)
}

Comment: Good! So the array you want to sum is `Array(dict.values)`. _Now_ can you do it?

Comment: Do you know how to get the total sum of an array of integers? This is a one-liner in Swift.

Comment: Try and __reduce__ this to it's simplest form.

Comment: @matt if you use the bare function, you don't need to create an intermediate array, just `dict.values` as the first parameter works just as well.

Comment: @Abizern Oh, nice point. That's even shorter!

Comment: @Abizern Alternatively you can use `dict` as the first parameter, but it still ends up as the same number of characters. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained in the documentations here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) You access and modify a dictionary through its methods and properties, or by using subscript syntax. Read the doc.

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
```

To access a value in your dictionary you can use the subscript syntax:

```
if let cola = dict["cola"] as? Int { // to read the value
    // Do something 
}
dict["cola"] = 30 // to change the value  
dict["pepsi"] = 25 // to add a new entry to your dictionary
dict["fanta"] = nil // to delete the fanta entry.
```

to read all the value in your dictionary

```
var sum = 0
for (drinkName, drinkValue) in dict {
    println("\(drinkName): \(drinkValue)")
    sum += drinkValue
}
```

or you can

```
var sum = 0
for drinkValue in dict.values {
   sum += drinkValue
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since an answer has been accepted and it isn't a very good one, I'm going to have to give up on the socratic method and show a more thematic way of answering this question.

Given your dictionary:

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
```

You get the sum by creating an array out of the `dict.values` and reducing them

```
let sum = Array(dict.values).reduce(0, +)
```

Or you could use the bare form of reduce which doesn't require the array to be created initially:

```
let sum = reduce(dict.values, 0, +)
```

Or the more modern version, since `reduce` is defined on an Array

```
let sum = dict.values.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Much better solution because it uses the advantages of Swift.

Comment: As of Swift 2.2, you can simply use dict.values.reduce(0, combine: +)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't use the power of swift

and the answer that does is outdated.

The simplest updated solution is:

```
 let valuesSum = dict.values.reduce(0, +)
```

start with zero, and sum the values of all the elements